# Visual C++ Express - Dozens of vcpkgsrv.exe

Tags: visual-c++, intellisense

I don't want to disable IntelliSense, but I don't see any other solution.

I have Visual C++ v10.0.30319.1, Max Cached Translation Units = 2. But still, dozens of vcpkgsrv.exe processes are spanned, consuming lots of memory (and rendering the computer unusable). Windows 7 Pro.

Any solution that you know of? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Tools > Extension manager > installed extensions > all**

Remove all the packages that are making problems like NuGet package in my case which eats all the memory... unistaling it here and restaring VS solved the problem, no need to reinstall whole windows.

**Make sure you unistall dependencies first**, dependencies are shown when you atempt to uninstall a package.

**NOTE:** if you don't uninstall dependencies the package won't be removed from the system and you'll probably have to reinstall VS or even whole windows.

**EDIT:**

Old solutions and projects must be deleted from the system, which means that you'll copy your .cpp and .h files and create new project because old projects may bring the problem back. I figured this out when I opened old projects and the problem was back.
After making new projects from old files everyting works as expected.

Comment: Well, in my case it was also 'time for wiping' (additional reasons involved). There you go, you got the accepted answer. :)

Comment: Thank you huff, I've (edited my post) aded additional info. hope this will help to the people having similar problem in the future.